# cy.get(...).selectFile is not a function Cypress

Tags: cypress

```
const IMAGE_INPUT = 'test-image-input';
const IMAGE_PATH = '/images/test.jpeg';

cy.get(`[data-element-id="${IMAGE_INPUT}"]`).selectFile(IMAGE_PATH, { force: true });
```

Returns: TypeError: cy.get(...).selectFile is not a function

I use Cypress 9.5.0, from what I know the selectFile functionality is supported since 9.3.0

I also use cypress-fail-fast 3.1.0

Comment: Are your globally and locally installed versions of Cypress both 9.5?